# In SignalR server side function calling twice in IE browser

Tags: jquery, asp.net, signalr

I am implementing chat application through Signal R. Its working fine in all other browser except IE,
the problem in IE browser is, the connecting function is calling twice.
How do i solve this Issue

Here is the code

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
$.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:8285/signalr/hubs";

$.connection.hub.start({ jsonp: true }, function () {
        Signal.server.connect().fail(function (e) {
            alert("");
        });

    });
```

I am using 0.5 Version, Asp.Net Web Application.
1. I have given full url here because it is cross browser $.connection.hub.url

Comment: "I am using 0.5 Version" Is that the version of SignalR you are using? If so, try updating to 1.1.3 http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR/1.1.3 and see if that changes anything

Comment: No.. I don't have that much time to implement, So please help me in this only

Comment: Update to 1.1.3 then remove "jQuery.support.cors = true;" Then read the documentation http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client

Comment: Hi dfowler, I have updated to 1.1.3 then also in IE 9.0 ver its firing event twice.

Comment: @dfowler, I have updated to 1.1.3 then also then also its firing event twice in IE 9.0 
`code`
http://localhost:12722/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js
http://localhost:12722/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.3.min.js 
http://localhost:12722/signalr/hubs

if ($.connection != null) 
{
  $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:12722/signalr/hubs';
  MyConnection = $.connection.MyConnection;
  $.connection.hub.start({ }, function () {
   MyConnection.server.connect().fail(function (e) {
        alert(e);
   });
  });
}
`code`

Comment: and also i have changed in Gloaba.asax `code` RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration() { EnableCrossDomain = true }); `code`

Comment: How many times are you calling `$.connection.hub.start()`

Comment: @TimBJames 100% i am calling only once.